# What's the meaning of "what prospectives to make superficies to seem body" in Bacon's essay?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

In Bacon's essay "of seeming wise", there is this sentence:

> It is a ridiculous thing, and fit for a satire to persons of judgment, to see what shifts these formalists have, and what prospectives to make superficies to seem body, that hath depth and bulk.

What's the meaning of "what prospectives" in this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

It is sense 5.a of *prospective* in the Oxford English Dictionary:

> a. The position from which one interprets or regards a situation; a point of view. *Obsolete. rare.*

A more recent writer would say *what views* or *what perspectives*.

Comment: +1 But how can you tell?

Comment: I don't know @tkp. It was obvious to me what it meant, so I went looking for it in a dictionary. I can't explain why it was obvious.

Comment: OK. I was hoping you might be into Bacon and so could explain the meaning of, *"...to make superfices to seem body..."*. In fact I'm kinda wishing that rather than just asking about the prospectives part, the OP had asked about the whole shebang. :-)

Comment: I was going to explain that bit, but you didn't ask, so I assumed you'd worked it out. It means "to make the surface (outside, appearance) appear to be the substance".

Comment: Ah, got it. Cool. So the whole is saying -- and obviously I'm *heavily* paraphrasing here -- something like: Anyone of any sense would find hilarious the extent to which some people will emphasize form over function?

Comment: Something like that, yes.